# Conversion to Backus-Naur Form

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf

What is the equivalent version of the line below in Backus-Naur Form?

```
func    :   type id '('  ')' '{' { type var_decl { ',' var_decl } ';' } { stmt } '}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func         : type id '('  ')' '{' func_body '}'
func_body    : decls stmts
decls        : decls decl | ε
decl         : type var_decl rem_var_decls ';'
rem_var_decls: rem_var_decls ',' var_decl | ε
stmts        : stmts stmt | ε
```